# Every basis of P_4 contains at least one polynomial of degree 3 or less?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Q. Every basis of P_4 contains at least one polynomial of degree 3 or less ?

I think this is easy to solve. . .. 
My English skill is so poor that i may not understand what the question is. . .
Please help !

Comment: Are you asking for proof of the statement? Or are you asking whether the statement is true? Either way, what is your attempt at solving?

Comment: Just to make sure that you are understanding it, it says that the answer to the following question is *no*: If $B$ is a basis for $P_4$, is it possible that every member of $B$ has degree $4$?

Comment: I want to know the counter example. . . .

Answer (score 2):

No. For example let $B=\{x^4,x^4+1,x^4+x,x^4+x^2,x^4+x^3\}$